# Exception: source is null for getProperty(null, "agent")

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I am just learning how to use tapestry and I keep coming across the following error

```
Exception: source is null for getProperty(null, "agent")    
ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2203)
```

This is the code in my html page

```
<tr>
          <td valign="center" align="right" height="30"><span class="label1"> <span key="agentDeletionSalesParentActivityType" />&nbsp;:&nbsp;</span></td>
          <td valign="center" align="left" height="30"><select jwcid="agentDeletionSalesParentActivityType@ActivityTypePropertySelection" regions="ognl:{activity.agent.region}" emptyOption="true" disabled="ognl:disabled" value="ognl:parentActivityType" /></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="center" align="right" height="30"><span class="label1"> <span key="agentDeletionSalesChildActivityType" />&nbsp;:&nbsp;</span></td>
            <td valign="center" align="left" height="30"><select jwcid="agentDeletionSalesChildActivityType" regions="ognl:{activity.agent.region}" emptyOption="true" disabled="ognl:disabled" value="ognl:childActivityType" parent="component:agentDeletionSalesParentActivityType" /></td>
          </tr>
```

This is my java code

```
@Persist
public abstract ActivityType getParentActivityType();
public abstract void setParentActivityType(ActivityType parent);

@Persist
public abstract ActivityType getChildActivityType();
public abstract void setChildActivityType(ActivityType child);

@Component(id="agentDeletionSalesChildActivityType", type="ActivityTypePropertySelection")
public abstract ActivityTypePropertySelection getChildActivityPropertySelection();
```

If you need more code i will be happy to put it up (kept it small so as not to pile code into the page), can anyone see why this is returning this exception?

Comment: Not really an answer, but it looks like you are using an old version of Tapestry (version 4?). As you are just starting with Tapestry I recommend using the newest version of Tapestry5

Comment: @NathanQ: Yes i am working with Tapestry 4, unfortunately this is the Tapestry that we are using here and I cannot change that so i have to learn this :/

Answer (score 2):

This would appear to be saying that that the `activity` object is null in this:

```
regions="ognl:{activity.agent.region}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to solve this one, but I was facing the problem.

The difference between you configuration and mine is the nested object reference

```
regions="ognl:{activity.agent.region}"
```

Since your exception states:

```
Exception: source is null for getProperty(null, "agent")
```

Based on my experience, this means that `activity` is indeed null, as @Stephen C says.

The exception I was recieving was:

```
Exception: source is null for getProperty(null, "question")
```

Here is my configuration. Hopefully, you may be able to gleam some insight.

SetSecurityQuestions.page

```
<component id="securityQuestion1Dropdown" type="PropertySelection">
    <binding name="model" value="securityQuestion1Model"/>
    <binding name="displayName" value="message:security_question_1"/>
    <binding name="value" value="securityQuestion1.question"/> <!-- the offending line -->
</component>
```

SetSecurityQuestions.html

```
<div class="formline">
    <span class="formtext">
         <span jwcid="@company:FieldLabelWithColon" 
               field="component:securityQuestion1Dropdown" 
               title="Security Question 1" 
               key="security_question1">Security Question 1</span>
        <span class="mandatory">*</span>
    </span>
    <select jwcid="securityQuestion1Dropdown" tabindex="1"/>
</div>
```

SetSecurityQuestions.java

```
@Persist("session")
@InitialValue("new com.org.net.SecurityQuestion()") // the solution
public abstract SecurityQuestion getSecurityQuestion1();
public abstract void setSecurityQuestion1(SecurityQuestion securityQuestion1);
```

Hope that helps.